# Dual Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 on 512Gb SSD GRUB Error

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

A client bought a Crucial MX100 SSD (Solid State Drive) 512Gb to be installed in their laptop and wanted a dual boot system with Windows 7 Professional 64-BIT on a 100Mb and 150Gb Primary Partition and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-BIT on a Primary Partition EXT4 with a 4.5Gb Primary SWAP Area. On Reboot I received GRUB Error... NO Such Partition Exists Grub Rescue. I attempted Boot Repair Disc but that also failed. URL of Boot Repair Summary is... http://paste.ubuntu.com/8115882/

I reinstalled Ubuntu with various partition sizes and as Primary and Logical partitions with the same issue and even reinstalled Windows using the entire drive and installed Ubuntu alongside windows. Same issue occurred and no dual boot is possible.

```
fdisk -l output of 512Gb SSD is...
Disk /dev/sdc1: 512.1 GB, 512110157824 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62260 cylinders, total 1000215152 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/sdc1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

fdisk -l output of my 120Gb Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation SSD (my Desktop) is
Disk /dev/sda2: 111.0 GB, 110956118016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13489 cylinders, total 216711168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/sda2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Any help or information would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Try Windows 7 Bootable Disc:

Create one/two partition as required for Windows with required size, leave the remaining hdd un-partitioned(will be used by Linux latter) ----> Install Windos and all it's components  ----> Reboot and verify for consistency.

Step 2:

Try Ubuntu Bootable Disc:

Create manual partition and select swap space as desired on the un-partitioned area ----> Complete Installation ----> Reboot to Windows and verify for consistency ----> Reboot to Linux and verify for consistency

Report Back(If Possible)